# 1 of 1 unhandled error Server Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setSearchResults' of '(0 , _SearchContext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, react-context

I keep getting this looping error whenever I put the SearchBar component back in the NavBar. [The page keeping refreshing and looping this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSSqp.png)

I'm trying to make the search function work, but I keep getting the same error. It worked fine on another branch, but not anymore. I ensure correct Provider hierarchy, imported everthing from the correct paths, but nothing works.

Here are the elements involved:

The `SearchBar.jsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useSearchContext from "./SearchContext";
import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";

const SearchBar = () => {
  const { setSearchResults } = useSearchContext();
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  // Remove the local data state

  const fetchData = () => {
    const url = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/multi?query=${searchTerm}&include_adult=false&language=en-US&page=1`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer token",
      },
    };
    fetch(url, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setSearchResults(result.results); // Update the context with the results
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex values-center space-x-2">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for a movie or a person..."
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
          className="px-2 py-1 border border-gray-300 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

The `SearchResults.jsx`:

```
import React from "react"
import useSearchContext from "./SearchContext"
import ResultCard from "./ResultCard"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"

const SearchResults = () => {
  const { searchResults } = useSearchContext() // Use the context to access the search results

  // Check if data is undefined or empty
  if (!searchResults || searchResults.length === 0) {
    return <div></div>
  }

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3}>
      {searchResults.map((item, index) => (
        <Grid item xs={3} key={index}>
          <ResultCard data={item} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  )
}

export default SearchResults
```

This is `SearchContext.jsx`:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react"

const SearchContext = createContext()

export default function useSearchContext() {
  return useContext(SearchContext)
}

export const SearchProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([])

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider value={{ searchResults, setSearchResults }}>
      {children}
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

My `_app.js`:

```
import "@/styles/globals.css"
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css"
import { SearchProvider } from "@/components/Navbar/SearchFunction/SearchContext"

config.autoAddCss = false
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SearchProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
     </SearchProvider>
  )
}
```